# How to use a non-default instance of ObjectCache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I set-up the object:

```
ObjectCache MyCache = new MemoryCache("MyCache");
```

Trying to use that instance in the future, and I tried this:

```
ObjectCache MyCache = MemoryCache("MyCache");
```

But gives an error.

I figured it works, because this code works:

```
ObjectCache DefaultCache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

But only lets me use the default cache.
I'm not sure how to use the `MyCache` instance I created in the future.  How do I do this?

Comment: You need to store that instance variable somewhere, and use it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created this `MyCache` variable instance you could store it as a static property to some class or configure it in your DI framework so that it gets automatically injected to all classes taking an `ObjectCache` constructor dependency.

Comment: How about when I load another page and try to use the stored data?

Comment: The documentation specifically says you cannot use the name to find the cache instance again, because multiple instances can have the same name `There is no mechanism to enforce unique names for cache instances. Therefore, it is possible to have multiple cache instances with the same name.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx  Note that if your app domain recycles, your static variable will be reinitialized to null, and you will have to reload the cache.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder: You would have a static property on an object accessible to each page, e.g. `public static ObjectCache MyNamedCache { get; set; }`.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder, simply store it in a static member that can be accessed from everywhere. If you don't know what a static member means then I invite you to read the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: `static` member gets stored in memory or what? I've never used it like this. (im new)  My understanding is to use `static` when I want to make an extension method

Comment: Yes, it gets stored in memory and it is accessible without an instance of the class. It's not only bound to extension methods. For example you could have a `public static ObjectCache MyCache = new MemoryCache("MyCache");` in some class and then access it with `SomeClass.MyCache` from anywhere in your code.